# Polar Plots in Julia

Tags: julia

I came across a Rose plot obtained with `Plots.jl` package in Julia:

https://goropikari.github.io/PlotsGallery.jl/src/rose.html

Two things are not clear to me. The first one is what is Julia doing on the line:

```
θ = 0:2pi/n:2pi
```

It seems that the output is (lower limit):(bin size):(upper limit) but I haven't seen this type of arithmetics previously where two ranges are divided. The second thing is that I would like to obtain a histogram polar plot as it was done with R ([Making a polar histogram in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564269/making-a-polar-histogram-in-ggplot2)), but I haven't found the documentation for line styles or how to do it in `Plots.jl`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `start:step:end` is a common syntax in creating ranges. Let's dissect the line:

```
# `pi` is a reserved variable name in Julia 
julia> pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

# A simple division
julia> 2pi/1
6.283185307179586

# Simple multiplication
julia> 2pi
6.283185307179586
```

So the `0:2pi/n:2pi` creates an object of type `StepRange` that starts from `0` up to `2pi` with steps of size `2pi/n`.
In the case of desired plot, you can use the `PlotlyJS.jl` package. As they provided an example [here](https://plotly.com/julia/polar-chart/). (Scroll down until you see "Polar Bar Chart")
I tested the code myself, and it's reproducible expectedly. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the R language.

```
julia> using RDatasets, DataFrames, PlotlyJS

julia> df = RDatasets.dataset("datasets", "iris");

julia> sepal = df.SepalWidth;

julia> plot(
           barpolar(
               r=sepal
           )
       )
```

Results in:
[image]